# Which QMAKE variable allows adding compiler flags for .mm sources, but not for .m sources?

Tags: objective-c, qt, qmake

There's a `QMAKE_CFLAGS` equivalent for objective-c sources: `QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS`. It applies to both `.m` and `.mm` files.
What variable corresponds to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`? Meaning, I need to add some compiler flags for `.mm` files, but not for `.m`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CXXFLAGS`